# Can rags and oven mits become non-kosher or be kashered?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

If kitchen rags or cloth oven mits have been used in a non-kosher kitchen, may they be used in a kosher kitchen after they are laundered? Or do they become non-kosher (for example, from contact with a hot non-kosher stove or hot non-kosher food) and require kashering? If so, how does one kasher cloth? Does it make a difference if the oven mits have some rubber or plastic on them, as opposed to being made solely of cloth?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35506/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes, IMO, but this one is more complete (also asks about kashering) and answered, so I suggest we close the other.

Comment: I asked a similar question once with the rabbinic response of: "it's fine as long as you dont eat your tablecloth"

Answer (score 7):

I am going to take the liberty of assuming rags and oven mitts are not any different than table cloths.

I asked the Star-K about kashering table cloths for Pesach, and was told that a table cloth can become "treif" and becomes pareve by putting it through the laundry machine.

I imagine the same would apply to any cloth or similar material.

Comment: Oven mitts touch keilim that are kli rison al haesh. (I don't know if that matters, but it seems like a possibly relevant distinction.)