# Kashrut of Oven Mitts

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Since kashrut often requires one to have separate sets of cooking utensils for dairy and meat, should one use separate dairy and meat oven mitts?

Comment: Do you touch food with the mitts?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35506/759

Comment: We do, but that's no proof.

Comment: I'm "injecting" a similar comment that my wife's Rav made when she asked him if you need separate table cloths for meat and dairy. He said, "When you eat the tablecloth, then worry about it." I would assume that the same answer applies to oven mitts. If the mitts are clean, I don't think you have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a written source for this, but I heard from my grandmother that the reason is just to be careful in case the oven mitts have food residue that spoiled onto them that would rub off onto the other pan. By using separate ones, you avoid that possibility.

Comment: This question has been marked duplicate. You may want to move your answer over to the [other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45196/5323), so that it will be more visible.